# What is the difference between a ring and a fixed ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, terminology

I'm struggling to understand what makes a ring fixed.  I'm working on the Pieri rule which requires a "set of linear combinations of the elements in the monoid with coefficients in a fixed ring."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really a mathematical term like "commutative", "algebraically closed" or "noetherian". What it really means is that you want to take some ring $R$ (for example, the integers or the rationals) to make some construction, and keep that same ring througout the discussion.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I thought that might be what it was, but I was afraid I was missing something.  Of course, it was the obvious answer.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Here ''fixed ring'' is used as a synonyms of ''a specific and given ring''.

Answer (score 1):

This depends also on the context. As said, it means that we fix one given ring. For Galois ring extensions, however, we speak of a *fixed ring of a Galois extension*, similarly to a *fixed field*. For example, see [here](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ojm/1200691824).